# Issue with hash storage resulting from password_verify() output

Tags: mariadb, php, password, encoding, hashing

Consider the following code:

```
$random_token = random_bytes(32);

$token_hash = password_hash(
  $random_token,
  PASSWORD_DEFAULT
);

$token_base64 = sodium_bin2base64(
  $random_token,
  SODIUM_BASE64_VARIANT_URLSAFE_NO_PADDING
);
```

`$token_hash` is then stored in a DB field of type `LONGTEXT` of the collation `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`. You do so by making a normal insert value using PDO, and to connect with PDO, you use:

```
$pdo = new PDO(
                dsn:      "mysql:host=host;dbname=db_name;charset=utf8mb4",
                username: 'username',
                password: 'password',
                options:  [
                              // Throw PDO Exception in case of any error
                              PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                              // Fetch the obtained result as associative array by default
                              PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
                          ]
            );
```

Upon retrieval of the token as base64-encoded URL parameter, you then retrieve the hash from the database using the same PDO connection syntax as above, and then do:

```
$random_token = sodium_base642bin(
  $token_base64,
  SODIUM_BASE64_VARIANT_URLSAFE_NO_PADDING
); 

$result = password_hash($random_token,$token_hash);
```

In like 10% of the cases, we get `false` for `$result`. How can this be? Are we maybe using the wrong collation / charset? Is it a problem that the PDO instance uses a slightly different charset vs the collation of the concerned field?

***UPDATE OF A CASE WHICH FAILED***:

An example of a failed hash verification occurred with this hash here:

`$2y$10$BkpF2otty42SSZS4dczmkeTJk7FJeqgt0D3oCuuOuqCKZG97OZtGu`

Comment: Please provide a sample hash.  I want to see whether utf8, etc, is actually needed.

Comment: Added above, cheers.

Comment: Hmmm.. No charset issues.

Comment: Apologies my bad that token came from an expired hash actually. Still, the hash verification is failing occasionally; will post a concerned hash as soon as I get news. But that means it could indeed happen that there's a problem if the DB connection uses a charset which is different from the DB field's collation?

Comment: At worst, there is case-folding -- meaning that ABcd would match ABCD, thereby making it slightly easier to hack.

Comment: Update added; we now have a case which failed.

Comment: @RickJames Would you mind continuing this discussion in chat? There's some stuff I'm not allowed to share in this feed here about this problem that could be a potential issue.

Comment: whatsapp?  Or something else?

Comment: If you feel comfortable over whatsapp, sure why not. But a chat in this forum is also already good enough, I really don't mind! Thanks a lot already in advance for your help! :)

Comment: See if this link lets you join a chat room here:  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/146028/rickjoe?tab=general

Comment: Ok, just sent a request to join

Comment: I found the Join button.  I have not seen anything where i need to authorize you to get in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146043/discussion-between-develjoe-and-rick-james).

Comment: I'm in the chat, but have not seen you there.